# Reducing the variable in calling a method in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using sklearn to perform linear regression. 
If i do

```
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_matrix, y)
```

it works fine. 
To reduce the code by removing the variable reg, i do

```
LinearRegression.reg.fit(x_matrix, y)
```

this gives me an error. Please explain the difference.

Python version 3.7.6

Comment: The difference is that in the second alternative python has no idea what `reg` is that you're referring to.

Comment: Agreed. I have changed accordingly. I wonder if it is a good practice to reduce the count of variables?

Comment: If you ever want to do another operation on the same object, you can't with option 2. Variable pollution isn't good but you don't really have to stress to reduce number of variables. The only important thing is that your code is **readable**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed the parentheses after `LinearRegression` and have an extra `reg` that does not belong there. Use:

```
LinearRegression().fit(x_matrix, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_matrix, y)
```

Like in a math equation, you may substitute the variable `reg` for its actual value (`LinearRegression()`)

Doing so will result in `LinearRegression().fit(x_matrix, y)`

Answer (score 1):

The thing with your code is that you forgot the brackets of creating a new object. Then you don't need to assign a name but use the object instantly.

Instead the short form has to look like this:

```
LinearRegression().fit(x_matrix, y)
```

This creates an object of the type LinearRegression which will then be used. It is probably just a little typo or copy and paste mistake though if you aren't sure what the difference between objects and types are you should look this up this is fundamental knowledge for python and a lot of other languages, too.

Answer (score 0):

The general difference is in the first instance you are creating an object of a class before calling the function of a class. In the second instance you are trying to directly use a function of the class without creating an object of the class first. This is only allowed when you have the function defined as @staticmethod.